# Как развернуть(деплой) YII2 на VPS хостинге в YII_ENV_PROD окружении?

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте.

Есть проект YII2 на Bitbucket версии 2.0.12, шаблон basic. Нужно его развернуть на VPS. Но в проекте есть папки /tests, /runtime, которые не нужны/создают нагрузку/занимают место на хостинге.
Нужно развернуть проект на продакшене в окружении YII_ENV_PROD и без папок /test & /runtime. Хоть это и VPS, но, из внешних пакетов, можно пользоваться только git & composer.
composer.json базовый.
gitignore для проекта тоже базовый:

```
# phpstorm project files
.idea

# netbeans project files
nbproject

# zend studio for eclipse project files
.buildpath
.project
.settings

# windows thumbnail cache
Thumbs.db

# composer vendor dir
/vendor

# composer itself is not needed
composer.phar

# Mac DS_Store Files
.DS_Store

# phpunit itself is not needed
phpunit.phar
# local phpunit config
/phpunit.xml

tests/_output/*
tests/_support/_generated
```

Вопрос:
Как корректно развернуть проект без этих лишних папок и в окружении YII_ENV_PROD?

Comment: Клонируете проект из гита, делаете `composer install` и готово. Какие проблемы?

Comment: При таком подходе копируется папка test а также никак не меняется окружение с YII_ENV_DEV на YII_ENV_PROD

Comment: Бахнуть `/test` и `index.php` в гитигнор, а после изменить в index режим на `prod` тоже не получится?